# Why typescript does not ensure type safety in a generic higher order component that adds additional properties in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, higher-order-components

I'm trying to create a generic higher order component and type safety is not checked. When doing the same but in a not generic way, the type safety is checked as expected.

```
interface IBaseProps {
  baseValue?: string;
}

const Base = (props: IBaseProps) => {
  return <span>{"value: " + props.baseValue}</span>;
};

interface IExtraProps {
  extraValue?: string;
}

const foo = <T extends IBaseProps>(
  Element: React.ComponentType<T>
): React.ComponentType<T & IExtraProps> => (props: T & IExtraProps) => {
  const baseValue = `${props.baseValue} extra value: ${props.extraValue}`;
  return <Element {...props} baseValue={baseValue} />; // example
};

const bar = <T extends IBaseProps>(
  Element: React.ComponentType<T>
): React.ComponentType<T & IExtraProps> => (props: T & IExtraProps) => {
  return <Element {...props} baseValue={42} />; // NO error, why?
};

const baz = <T extends IBaseProps>(
  Element: React.ComponentType<T>
): React.ComponentType<T & IExtraProps> => (props: T & IExtraProps) => {
  return <Element {...props} unknownProp={42} />; // NO error, why?
};

const bag = (props:IBaseProps) => {
  const baseValue = props.baseValue + ' augmented'
  return <Base {...props} baseValue={42} />; // ok, error is detected
}
```

Demo can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sotstypesafety-nvro3?file=/src/App.tsx)

How to make Typescript check types correctly?

Comment: This is a great question!  I'm puzzled by your demo and I cannot answer, unfortunately.  I haven't come across this because usually with an HOC I'm removing prop requirements (by generating them) rather than adding additional required props.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is right with typescript. The Base component is declared above and has a type to IBaseProps.That is why it shows an error.

The bar has

```
React.ComponentType<T & IExtraProps>
```

It basically means that T can be any type. So it is not showing any errors.

The others also have T & IExtraProps types.
Check it by hovering to any of them ( bar, baz , foo , bag ). Everything is working correctly in this code.